# WPF Storyboard Animation Loops Forever Even After Being Set

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a  a custom user control to animate based on a `DependencyProperty` which is bound to a `DataTrigger`. If the `DependencyProperty` is equal to *Failure*, it should animate the fill color of a rectangle (named buttonColor) within the user control.

For some reason though, it always loops forever even if I set the `RepeatBehavior` to any value including 1.

If I remove the RepeatBehavior attribute, it only plays the animation once (as expected). Here is the code which I have the issue:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ButtonAction.Status}" Value="Failure">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Pulse"/>

        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="1">
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="buttonColor"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" 
                                To="{StaticResource FailedColor}" 
                                AutoReverse="True" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The correct syntax to repeat `N` times is:

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Nx">
```

for example:

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="6x">
```

Comment: Ah thank you this fixed my problem. Except to note that it must be a lower case 'x'

Answer (score 1):

Setting a duration value will also limit the repeat behavior as it takes precedence.  So if you have repeat behavior set on the ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames tag but on the storyboard you set a Duration="0:0:4" then the animation will only repeat for 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear and to add onto the answer, if one actually wants to repeat continuously one can set the `RepeatBehavior` to `Forever` such as here where I am rotating a vector around its center point.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ChaseRotate" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
         <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="360"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

See [How to: Rotate an Object - WPF .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-rotate-an-object?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Full Example for [Chasing Circles in Xaml](https://gist.github.com/CheetahChrome/6fca3b3882976cb56afa850a60943867).