# XAML Storyboard - Looping a KeyFrame

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

So I've been playing around with Visual Studio for Windows Phone 8 and was exploring the XAML mark up language that's associated with WP8 and WPF applications. I read some guides on Storyboards and animating with Keyframes and this brings me to my question. Aside from the timed animation with Storyboards is there a way to make it repeat a section until a button is pressed (Click to start, click to stop)?

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" x:Name="Testboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="510.72" KeySpline="1,0,1,1" />
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="6000.43"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="9000" KeySpline="0,0,0,1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

I have a Storyboard setup and the image is a little roulette wheel. The animation has 3 stages:

1. KeyTime 0:0:2 is when the wheel begins to spin slowly picking up speed using the Keyspline.
2. KeyTime 0:0:5 is where it just spins to fake the look of momentum.
3. KeyTime 0:0:7 is where it slows to a halt.

On the .cs side of things, I have a button wired up to generate a random value to replace the last Keyframe so that it stops spinning on a different slot each time. Then I call the Storyboard to begin.

```
    private void btnStartWheel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sb = (Storyboard)this.FindName("Testboard");
        ((SplineDoubleKeyFrame)((DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)sb.Children[0]).KeyFrames[3]).Value = wheel.getAngle();
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

I've tried using a timer that on tick would check where the position is in the story board, and if it's nearing the end of Keyframe[2] (KeyTime 0:0:5) it would use the seek() method and shift it back to the start of the frame. The problem with that method is that it completely killed the animation and started it from a value of 0 as opposed to it pre-spinning from Keyframe[1].

Basically I would like it to:

- Press a button to start the animation.
- Loop in Keyframe[2] without losing the rotation look until the button is pressed again.
- After the button is pressed break the loop and finish the Storyboard.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="6x">

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032404/wpf-storyboard-animation-loops-forever-even-even-with-repeatbehavior-6

Comment: I know about the RepeatBehavior, however I would only like one Keyframe to repeat, not the whole animation. I'm beginning to think the only thing I can do is have it switch out storyboards as I go along but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I think that you can get the value from stopped SplineDoubleKeyFrame and start from it in the new SplineDoubleKeyFrame. Didn't tried, but looks possible.